# How to display data from Model in HTML table in .NET core (cshtml)?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm a newb at .NET core and am working on some basics.
I have a text file like this:

**employees.txt**

```
Naruto Uzumaki,19,150000
Sasuke Uchiha,18,140000
Hinata Hyuga,17,100000
Itachi Uchiha,22,200000
Nara Shikamaru,20,90000
```

and I'm trying to display this data inside an HTML table like this, using c# (Razor) within the HTML tags:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<table id = "empTable">
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
   </tr>
@{
    foreach (string line in Model) {
    <tr>
       string[] values = line[i].Split(',');
       for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
       {
          values[i] = values[i].Trim();
          <td>@values[i]</td>
       }
    </tr>
    }
}
<table>
```

But obviously this isn't working for me, and whenever I wrap the  tags within Razor like I did above, it messes with the code and I get errors like ***"The name 'values' does not exist in the current context"*** and ***"End of file or an unexpected character was reached before the "" tag could be parsed."***

I've tried a different method, where I attempt to pass a C# string array into my Javascript code so I can edit the innerHTML of my table tag instead, but it also doesn't work and I figure it's not that easy either. I've looked at solutions such as serializing the C# string array, or using StringBuilder in C# to dynamically create an HTML table, but I'm not sure where to include the namespace within the .NET folder nor how it really works.

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Add the view model definition to you post, please.

Answer (score 3):

The thing here is that you are not using Razor and C# correctly

At first: Do your operations and string interpolations in your C# code and give out the fully parsed and splitted string to the model. Keep out as much logic from your razor as you can. (Which makes it possible to unit test your logic)

So instead of splitting your string within your razor code, you could define a new model like

```
public class LineModel {
    private string _name;
    private int _first;
    private int _second;

    public string Name { get => _name; }
    public int FirstNumber { get => _first; }
    public int SecondNumber { get => _second; }
    public void FormatLine(string line){
        // string splitting here
    }
}
```

Then add every line to your ViewModel so you have an IEnumerable (maybe a List) within your ViewModel.

And within your razor code you can do sth like this:

```
@foreach(var line in Model.Lines) {
    <tr>
        <td>@line.Name</td>
        <td>@line.FirstNumber</td>
        <td>@line.SecondNumber</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Please be aware that my code might not be syntactically correct, as i did not do a lot of razor recently. But this is the approach I would recommend, because

1.) it separates the logic from presentation

2.) it is much more maintainable

3.) it is unit testable

4.) it is more deterministic

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This worked extremely well. I'm very new to .NETcore so I had to figure out what models were but thank you so much for this.